# d3 graphs on google maps with link between nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, d3.js

My Requirement is to show the d3 graphs on google maps with multiple nodes and links between them. i have tried the following snippet. But it is not at all working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js">        </script>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body,
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.stations,
.stations svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.links {
    position: absolute;
}

.stations svg {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 4;
}

.stations circle {
    fill: blue;
    stroke: none;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
         var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-22.1629209, -47.9922608),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP
      });

var dataset = JSON.parse('{"directed": true, "graph": [], "nodes": [{"lat": 44.391643516091975, "lng": 23.159677682342053}, {"lat": 44.315988, "lng": 23.818359, "id": "a:a::"},  {"lat": 44.29844994776969, "lng": 24.402314492323608, "id": "b:b"},  {"lat": 44.351118152120485, "lng": 23.341791630955303, "id": "a:c"},  {"lat": 44.889424527442685, "lng": 23.960970697645276, "id": "e:d"},  {"lat": 43.46084400349923, "lng": 23.975774627524885, "id": "d:6104:1"},  {"lat": 44.64680010013528, "lng": 23.20292820976948, "id": "c:6104:2"},  {"lat": 44.40446080879215, "lng": 23.953536570796015, "id": "b:6104:3"},  {"lat": 44.18593375168617, "lng": 23.769879901486856, "id": "af:6104:4"},  {"lat": 44.09051846584001, "lng": 24.14130778735744},  {"lat": 44.66376251969314, "lng": 23.77379490100736},  {"lat": 44.6240449587762, "lng": 24.08347249542858, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:6f06"},  {"lat": 45.00138334367271, "lng": 24.092331272179138, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:1306"},  {"lat": 44.55033831045195, "lng": 24.312914121854526, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:ef05"},  {"lat": 44.74421652327631, "lng": 24.728457702115804, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:ea03"},  {"lat": 43.79401723931746, "lng": 23.77846416630604, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7200"},  {"lat": 43.67351687345779, "lng": 23.00140978137842, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:5d07"},  {"lat": 43.87692500855015, "lng": 24.28543591328852, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:550b"},  {"lat": 44.28189405244278, "lng": 23.972410391551893, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:2706"},  {"lat": 43.94916218711252, "lng": 23.9733463072956},  {"lat": 44.61479884874806, "lng": 24.27581898293906},  {"lat": 44.92223011339065, "lng": 23.505887513934034},  {"lat": 44.20117807597118, "lng": 23.70555450810448, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:2603"},  {"lat": 43.547714841247966, "lng": 24.56985383484244, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:2601"},  {"lat": 43.92116991202797, "lng": 22.82805535024416, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:5803"},  {"lat": 44.56587414638437, "lng": 22.970799697228976, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7406"},  {"lat": 44.10230727065641, "lng": 23.701204095342597, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7407"},  {"lat": 45.25416535851712, "lng": 24.434312172789625, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7404"},  {"lat": 44.91647619491961, "lng": 23.678252259828515, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7405"},  {"lat": 45.03473433359779, "lng": 24.07596179597473},  {"lat": 45.16855171992733, "lng": 23.435986773864467},  {"lat": 44.553669079256146, "lng": 23.05123326220677},  {"lat": 43.32871087231798, "lng": 23.325707869122013, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:5308"},  {"lat": 43.40444516345915, "lng": 23.485798521785892, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:f107"},  {"lat": 43.9435337313432, "lng": 22.968285824722354},  {"lat": 44.74549949495889, "lng": 22.832034225254052},  {"lat": 44.34901730307382, "lng": 24.33506529636527},  {"lat": 43.53125851464172, "lng": 24.763229039168245, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:6602"},  {"lat": 44.155575603194634, "lng": 23.250881840942217, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:e300"}], "links": [ {"source": 1, "target": 25},  {"source": 1, "target": 26},  {"source": 1, "target": 27},  {"source": 1, "target": 28},  {"source": 1, "target": 29},  {"source": 1, "target": 30},  {"source": 1, "target": 31},  {"source": 1, "target": 34},  {"source": 1, "target": 35},  {"source": 1, "target": 36},  {"source": 3, "target": 5},  {"source": 3, "target": 6},  {"source": 4, "target": 15},  {"source": 4, "target": 9},  {"source": 5, "target": 19},  {"source": 5, "target": 23},  {"source": 6, "target": 18},  {"source": 6, "target": 20},  {"source": 7, "target": 22},  {"source": 8, "target": 37},  {"source": 8, "target": 3},  {"source": 10, "target": 11},  {"source": 17, "target": 21}, {"source": 18, "target": 13}, {"source": 18, "target": 14}, {"source": 19, "target": 33}, {"source": 19, "target": 38}, {"source": 23, "target": 2}, {"source": 25, "target": 10}, {"source": 28, "target": 4}, {"source": 28, "target": 17}, {"source": 29, "target": 32}, {"source": 32, "target": 25}, {"source": 34, "target": 24}, {"source": 35, "target": 8}, {"source": 35, "target": 16}, {"source": 37, "target": 7}, {"source": 37, "target": 12}], "multigraph": false}');

 d3.json(dataset, function (json) {
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();        

    // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
    overlay.onAdd = function () {

        var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer)
            .append("div")
            .attr("height", "100%")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("class", "stations");
        overlay.draw = function () {
            var radius = 5;
            var projection = this.getProjection(),
                padding = 10;


            var node_coord = {};

            var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
                .data(d3.entries(dataset))
                .each(transform) // update existing markers
                .enter().append("svg:svg")
                .each(transform)
                .attr("class", "marker");
            marker.append("svg:circle")
                .attr("r", radius)
                .attr("cx", padding)
                .attr("cy", padding);


            var markerLink = layer.selectAll(".links")
                .data(d3.entries(dataset))
                .each(pathTransform) // update existing markers       
                .enter().append("svg:svg")
                .attr("class", "links")
                .each(pathTransform);

            function pathTransform(d) {
                var t, b, l, r, w, h, currentSvg;
                var d1 = new Object();
                var d2 = new Object();
                $(this).empty();
                d1.x = node_coord[d.source + "," + 0]
                d1.y = node_coord[d.source + "," + 1]
                d2.x = node_coord[d.target + "," + 0]
                d2.y = node_coord[d.target + "," + 1]

                if (d1.y < d2.y) {
                    t = d1.y;
                    b = d2.y;
                } else {
                    t = d2.y;
                    b = d1.y;
                }
                if (d1.x < d2.x) {
                    l = d1.x;
                    r = d2.x;
                } else {
                    l = d2.x;
                    r = d1.x;
                }
                currentSvg = d3.select(this)
        .style("z-index", "1")
        .style("left", (l + 2 * radius) + "px")
                    .style("top", (t + 2 * radius) + "px")
                    .style("width", (r - l + 2 * radius) + "px")
                    .style("height", (b - t + 2 * radius) + "px");


                var x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;
                if ((d1.y < d2.y) && (d1.x < d2.x)) {
                    x2 = r - l;
                    y2 = b - t;
                } else if ((d1.x > d2.x) && (d1.y > d2.y)) {
                    x2 = r - l;
                    y2 = b - t;
                } else if ((d1.y < d2.y) && (d1.x > d2.x)) {
                    x1 = r - l;
                    y2 = b - t;
                } else if ((d1.x < d2.x) && (d1.y > d2.y)) {
                    x1 = r - l;
                    y2 = b - t;
                }
                currentSvg.append("svg:line")
                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style("stroke", "black")
                        .attr("x1", x1)
                        .attr("y1", y1)
                        .attr("x2", x2)
                        .attr("y2", y2);

                return currentSvg;
            }

            function transform(d, i) {
                d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.lng);
                d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);

                node_coord[i + "," + 0] = d.x;
                node_coord[i + "," + 1] = d.y;

                return d3.select(this)
                    .style("left", (d.x) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d.y) + "px");
            }
            layer.append("div")
                .attr("class", "stations.line");

        };

    };

    // Bind our overlay to the map…
    overlay.setMap(map);
});
```

when i tried to implement the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711) which plots only the nodes, It works well. But i need to create a link between those nodes using the source and target details in the link object.

Need to show the kind of graph (attached) over google maps. where each node represents location.[image: My Requirement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code. The dataset bonded to the links and nodes are not correct.  You have to set the array of nodes to the node elements and array of links to the link elements.

Instead of following code,

```
 var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
   .data(d3.entries(dataset)) //Replace this line
   .each(transform) 
   .enter().append("svg:svg")
   .each(transform)
   .attr("class", "marker");

 marker.append("svg:circle")
   .attr("r", radius)
   .attr("cx", padding)
   .attr("cy", padding);   

 var markerLink = layer.selectAll(".links")
   .data(d3.entries(dataset)) //Replace this line
   .each(pathTransform)
   .enter().append("svg:svg")
   .attr("class", "links")
   .each(pathTransform);
```

use following code.

```
var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
   .data(dataset.nodes) 
   .each(transform) // update existing markers
   .enter().append("svg:svg")
   .each(transform)
   .attr("class", "marker");
 marker.append("svg:circle")
   .attr("r", radius)
   .attr("cx", padding)
   .attr("cy", padding);

 var markerLink = layer.selectAll(".links")
   .data(dataset.links)
   .each(pathTransform) // update existing markers       
   .enter().append("svg:svg")
   .attr("class", "links")
   .each(pathTransform);
```

**Working code snippet:**

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-22.1629209, -47.9922608),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP
  });

  var dataset = JSON.parse('{"directed": true, "graph": [], "nodes": [{"lat": 44.391643516091975, "lng": 23.159677682342053}, {"lat": 44.315988, "lng": 23.818359, "id": "a:a::"},  {"lat": 44.29844994776969, "lng": 24.402314492323608, "id": "b:b"},  {"lat": 44.351118152120485, "lng": 23.341791630955303, "id": "a:c"},  {"lat": 44.889424527442685, "lng": 23.960970697645276, "id": "e:d"},  {"lat": 43.46084400349923, "lng": 23.975774627524885, "id": "d:6104:1"},  {"lat": 44.64680010013528, "lng": 23.20292820976948, "id": "c:6104:2"},  {"lat": 44.40446080879215, "lng": 23.953536570796015, "id": "b:6104:3"},  {"lat": 44.18593375168617, "lng": 23.769879901486856, "id": "af:6104:4"},  {"lat": 44.09051846584001, "lng": 24.14130778735744},  {"lat": 44.66376251969314, "lng": 23.77379490100736},  {"lat": 44.6240449587762, "lng": 24.08347249542858, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:6f06"},  {"lat": 45.00138334367271, "lng": 24.092331272179138, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:1306"},  {"lat": 44.55033831045195, "lng": 24.312914121854526, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:ef05"},  {"lat": 44.74421652327631, "lng": 24.728457702115804, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:ea03"},  {"lat": 43.79401723931746, "lng": 23.77846416630604, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7200"},  {"lat": 43.67351687345779, "lng": 23.00140978137842, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:5d07"},  {"lat": 43.87692500855015, "lng": 24.28543591328852, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:550b"},  {"lat": 44.28189405244278, "lng": 23.972410391551893, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:2706"},  {"lat": 43.94916218711252, "lng": 23.9733463072956},  {"lat": 44.61479884874806, "lng": 24.27581898293906},  {"lat": 44.92223011339065, "lng": 23.505887513934034},  {"lat": 44.20117807597118, "lng": 23.70555450810448, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:2603"},  {"lat": 43.547714841247966, "lng": 24.56985383484244, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:2601"},  {"lat": 43.92116991202797, "lng": 22.82805535024416, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:5803"},  {"lat": 44.56587414638437, "lng": 22.970799697228976, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7406"},  {"lat": 44.10230727065641, "lng": 23.701204095342597, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7407"},  {"lat": 45.25416535851712, "lng": 24.434312172789625, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7404"},  {"lat": 44.91647619491961, "lng": 23.678252259828515, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:7405"},  {"lat": 45.03473433359779, "lng": 24.07596179597473},  {"lat": 45.16855171992733, "lng": 23.435986773864467},  {"lat": 44.553669079256146, "lng": 23.05123326220677},  {"lat": 43.32871087231798, "lng": 23.325707869122013, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:5308"},  {"lat": 43.40444516345915, "lng": 23.485798521785892, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:f107"},  {"lat": 43.9435337313432, "lng": 22.968285824722354},  {"lat": 44.74549949495889, "lng": 22.832034225254052},  {"lat": 44.34901730307382, "lng": 24.33506529636527},  {"lat": 43.53125851464172, "lng": 24.763229039168245, "id": "aaaa3bab:3d:6602"},  {"lat": 44.155575603194634, "lng": 23.250881840942217, "id": "aaaa3bab:3c:e300"}], "links": [ {"source": 1, "target": 25},  {"source": 1, "target": 26},  {"source": 1, "target": 27},  {"source": 1, "target": 28},  {"source": 1, "target": 29},  {"source": 1, "target": 30},  {"source": 1, "target": 31},  {"source": 1, "target": 34},  {"source": 1, "target": 35},  {"source": 1, "target": 36},  {"source": 3, "target": 5},  {"source": 3, "target": 6},  {"source": 4, "target": 15},  {"source": 4, "target": 9},  {"source": 5, "target": 19},  {"source": 5, "target": 23},  {"source": 6, "target": 18},  {"source": 6, "target": 20},  {"source": 7, "target": 22},  {"source": 8, "target": 37},  {"source": 8, "target": 3},  {"source": 10, "target": 11},  {"source": 17, "target": 21}, {"source": 18, "target": 13}, {"source": 18, "target": 14}, {"source": 19, "target": 33}, {"source": 19, "target": 38}, {"source": 23, "target": 2}, {"source": 25, "target": 10}, {"source": 28, "target": 4}, {"source": 28, "target": 17}, {"source": 29, "target": 32}, {"source": 32, "target": 25}, {"source": 34, "target": 24}, {"source": 35, "target": 8}, {"source": 35, "target": 16}, {"source": 37, "target": 7}, {"source": 37, "target": 12}], "multigraph": false}');

  d3.json(dataset, function(json) {
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
    overlay.onAdd = function() {

      var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer)
        .append("div")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("class", "stations");
      overlay.draw = function() {
        var radius = 5;
        var projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 10;


        var node_coord = {};

        var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
          .data(dataset.nodes)
          .each(transform) // update existing markers
          .enter().append("svg:svg")
          .each(transform)
          .attr("class", "marker");
        marker.append("svg:circle")
          .attr("r", radius)
          .attr("cx", padding)
          .attr("cy", padding);


        var markerLink = layer.selectAll(".links")
          .data(dataset.links)
          .each(pathTransform) // update existing markers       
          .enter().append("svg:svg")
          .attr("class", "links")
          .each(pathTransform);

        function pathTransform(d) {
          var t, b, l, r, w, h, currentSvg;
          var d1 = new Object();
          var d2 = new Object();
          $(this).empty();
          d1.x = node_coord[d.source + "," + 0]
          d1.y = node_coord[d.source + "," + 1]
          d2.x = node_coord[d.target + "," + 0]
          d2.y = node_coord[d.target + "," + 1]

          if (d1.y < d2.y) {
            t = d1.y;
            b = d2.y;
          } else {
            t = d2.y;
            b = d1.y;
          }
          if (d1.x < d2.x) {
            l = d1.x;
            r = d2.x;
          } else {
            l = d2.x;
            r = d1.x;
          }
          currentSvg = d3.select(this)
            .style("z-index", "1")
            .style("left", (l + 2 * radius) + "px")
            .style("top", (t + 2 * radius) + "px")
            .style("width", (r - l + 2 * radius) + "px")
            .style("height", (b - t + 2 * radius) + "px");


          var x1 = 0,
            y1 = 0,
            x2 = 0,
            y2 = 0;
          if ((d1.y < d2.y) && (d1.x < d2.x)) {
            x2 = r - l;
            y2 = b - t;
          } else if ((d1.x > d2.x) && (d1.y > d2.y)) {
            x2 = r - l;
            y2 = b - t;
          } else if ((d1.y < d2.y) && (d1.x > d2.x)) {
            x1 = r - l;
            y2 = b - t;
          } else if ((d1.x < d2.x) && (d1.y > d2.y)) {
            x1 = r - l;
            y2 = b - t;
          }
          currentSvg.append("svg:line")
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .attr("x1", x1)
            .attr("y1", y1)
            .attr("x2", x2)
            .attr("y2", y2);

          return currentSvg;
        }

        function transform(d, i) {
          console.log("here");
          d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.lng);
          d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);

          node_coord[i + "," + 0] = d.x;
          node_coord[i + "," + 1] = d.y;

          return d3.select(this)
            .style("left", (d.x) + "px")
            .style("top", (d.y) + "px");
        }
        layer.append("div")
          .attr("class", "stations.line");

      };

    };

    // Bind our overlay to the map…
    overlay.setMap(map);
  });
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.stations,
.stations svg {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.links {
  position: absolute;
}
.stations svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 4;
}
.stations circle {
  fill: blue;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Works Perfect..Thanks a lot

Comment: One more question to you. What i need to change here in order to show arrow from source to target node as like in my attached sample? i tried to add  the following where i define the links. But it is not working.                            .style("marker-end", "url(#suit)")
                    .attr('marker-start', function (d) {
                        return d.birectional ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : null;
                    });

Comment: Have you added suit and start-arrow markers to the defs?? Ensure you have defined them with the corresponding ids.

Comment: i have added like this..                        

 layer.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
            .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
          .enter().append("marker")
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d; })
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 12)
            .attr("refY", 0)
            .attr("markerWidth", 6)
            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
          .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
            .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
            .style("opacity", "1");

Comment: NithyaShree, i think this will not work since layour is div and not an svg element. You have to append defs to the svg container of links.

Comment: If i change my div to svg, the google maps itself not coming through. Can you help me to get out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can solely do it with d3 for drawing svg lines.

I am using the google *google.maps.Polyline* for generating lines

Something like this:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 36.98, lng: -120.12},//start point of line
    {lat: 37.37, lng: -121.92},//end point of line1
    {lat: 37.28, lng: -120.50},//end point of line2
    {lat:37.70, lng:-121.82}//end point of line3
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ga1jhkzb/2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. it works. It allows me to draw lines between two nodes. But It need like a foreach loop for that polyline.

Comment: If you need a single line joining all the points then you will need to make the array flightPlanCoordinates accordingly. 
You can give this doc a read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple ... it covers all the possible ways you can draw using google map  *Drawing on the map*

Comment: Yes. but i can make a continuous line there. Not as the image i attached in my question.